# How I keep the web application running?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I created a responsive web application and I'm trying to create a Google Chrome Extension for it.
I've just used an iframe which work correctly.
However, I'd like to keep it running in order to be able to leave the extension/reopen without reset (without returning to the start url) and keep the full state of the current page in the extension.
It's like keeping the process live in background.

How can I do this ?

Comment: There's a "background" permission (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#bg), though I'm not sure whether it's what you want.

Comment: It's maybe a little part of the solution ;-)